# wp7 sdk and wp8 device

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'have windows phone 8 device(lumia 620). I'm working on visual studio 2010. My problem is that I cannot run my XNA app with my phone. Every time I click start debugging, this error pops up

```
Error   1   Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that Zune software is launched.      0   0
```

Zune is working but zune says no devices connected. The windows phone desktop application is working fine and connects to my phone. What should I do. What is my fault.

Comment: I'm not sure, but a quick google search revealed this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwinphone/thread/d8e781ac-34b9-4500-8245-b54f04595e31/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't deploy to  wp8 device from vs2010, you need vs2012 and wp8 sdk even if the app is developed for wp7.1

Answer (score 0):

To run applications on your WP8 device you need the WP8 SDK and this requires VS2012. When you develop an XNA game you can only target WP 7.0 and 7.1 even when running on a WP8 device as the WP 8.0 OS uses C++ for games and no longer supports XNA. One final note, if you decide to develop your game using XNA/VS2012 you will need to use VS2010 to build your content as the content pipeline is not supported in VS2012.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score -2):

You should select Device option in the standard toolbar of Visual Studio.